# How to invoke a CloudPage from inside a Custom JB Activity and pass input parameters to it?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, ssjs, cloudpage, custom-activity

We have some SSJS/AMPScript code embedded in a cloudpage which we want to invoke from a Custom JB Activity and pass some parameters to it as input.

Please advise how we can achieve this. Any sample code/example will also be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Keddy

Answer (score 1):

Do not expose any functionality on a public CloudPage without an authentication mechanism.
Otherwise, you are essentially building a public function for anyone stumbling across your URL.

This has been covered well here:
http://www.devsutd.com/writing-a-rest-service-using-cloud-pages/

Code Resources are the way to go (the above applies in the same way.) as they do not consume a super message per page impression, unlike CloudPages.

When using URL-located services, after authentication, all you need to do is to send an HTTP Post request with parameters to the URL:

```
POST [CloudPage URL]
Headers:
Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded
accept-encoding: gzip
```

With x-www-form-urlencoded, the payload has to be formatted as a key value pair in this form:
key1=value1&key2=value2

to reach the page and be interpreted, not JSON format or similar.

These incoming parameters can then be retrieved on the CloudPage using RequestParameter() function. If you need to encrypt/decrypt parameters, encryptSymmetric() and decryptsymmetric() AMPScript functions are quite helpful.